# NullPointException when trying to add component dynamically (android)

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-fragments, android-view

There are numerous tutorials and answers but none of them worked for me, did something change in android sdk recently to render those samples incorrect or am I making a silly mistake..?

I am trying to add a ViewText component dynamically depending on whether bluetooth is enabled or not.

Here's the on create method of MainActivityClass:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        TextView BAMessage = new TextView(this);
        BAMessage.setText("Bluetooth is disabled.");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(BAMessage, lp);
    }
```

If I comment out last 3 lines the app does not crash so I am quite sure the issue is with those 3 lines. I don't really understand how the findViewById works since only one out of at least 20 code samples I looked at actually showed where "activity_main" comes from, and it doesn't work anyways. Is "activity_main" supposed to be the id in fragment_main.xml root element? What if I want to create all elements dynamically?

Here's my fragment_main.xml file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/app_info_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_info_message" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Stack Trace:

```
  04-22 20:06:20.127: D/AndroidRuntime(5306): Shutting down VM
    04-22 20:06:20.127: W/dalvikvm(5306): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ce6d88)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306): Process: com.dominicm.multilight, PID: 5306
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dominicm.multilight/com.dominicm.multilight.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at com.dominicm.multilight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
    04-22 20:06:20.127: E/AndroidRuntime(5306):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please, include your stack trace.

Comment: I am new to android dev, can you clarify what the stack trace is and how to access it. I am using eclipse.

Comment: Just click on the tab that says `LogCat`, there the log of your app will be stored and you probably have an exception here, which corresponds to the stack trace of the error that has been fired.

Comment: Trace added, see edit.

Comment: Then probably @Krylez's answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the fragment's views in the activity layout. Try moving the code where you add the view to the PlaceHolderFragment's `onCreateView()` method:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView BAMessage = new TextView(getActivity());
        BAMessage.setText("Bluetooth is disabled.");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(BAMessage, lp);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Can you comment the code especially the parts different from my code or add a link to a sample/tutorial with this code?

Comment: That's a pretty broad request and it probably doesn't belong in comments. Would you be interested in discussing further questions over chat?

Comment: Well I was thinking more along the lines of editing the question by adding code comments and or text where necessary so it's available to everyone. Specifically I am confused why so many samples I came across are like my example and why it doesn't work. Also what is difference between addView and setContentView in this respect? I want to do it the "right" way but I cant find any definitive sources like android reference examples and I don't fully understand why this code over other samples should work.

Comment: A chat would be very useful too though :)

Comment: Well you've probably seen Activity-only tutorials. Modern Android apps are driven by Fragments, which live in Activities. The Fragment's layout isn't directly accessible to its container Activity.

Comment: As for the difference between addView and setContentView, those belong to different classes. ViewGroup is a special type of View that can contain other Views. The addView() method can be called to a ViewGroup to add a View to its existing contents. The setContentView() method belongs to Activity and it will replace all of the Activity's current contents (if any).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51210/discussion-between-krylez-and-dominicm)